# python database insert formatting

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to insert into a postgresql database in python 3.6 and currently am trying to execute this line

```
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO "+table_name+"(price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",(exchange_rate, buy_rate, sell_rate, date))
```

but every time it tries to run the table name has ' ' around it so it turns out like INSERT INTO table_name('12', ..., ..., ...) ... instead of 
INSERT INTO table_name(12, ..., ..., ...) ... how can I make the string formatter leave the quotes out or remove them or something? It is causing a syntax error around the 12 because it doesn't need the single quotes.

Comment: use triple quotes `cur.execute('''  <your query here>  ''')`

Comment: Don't do that, i.e. don't use the string formatting, this will make your code vulnerable to sql inject attacks. Use query parameters instead.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Answer (score 1):

Use it with triple quotes. Also you may pass table_name as a element of second parameter, too.

```
 cur.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",(table_name, exchange_rate, buy_rate, sell_rate, date))
```

More detailed approach;

- Triple qoutes give developers a change to write SQL query as multi-lines.
- Also it allows you to use single and double qoutes without escaping from them. (It is beneficiary for complex SQL Queries but you don't need that on your case)

Comment: That works except when i added the tablename back it complains about the quotes around the table INSERT INTO 'my_table' (... should not have the quotes around the my_table. how is this avoided?

Comment: Why you are not using it as we shared and explained? As @redneb said, your method is vulnerable to injection attacks. Explain your purpose and we may found another solution for your needs.

Comment: I did exactly what you commented with and as a result of that the first %s for the table name is wrapped in ' '. This is a syntax error and is breaking the query. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use the new string formatting to have a clean representation. `%s` is explicitly converting to a string, you don't want that. Format chooses the most fitting type for you.

```
table_name = "myTable"
exchange_rate = 1
buy_rate = 2
sell_rate = 3
date = 123
x = "INSERT INTO {0} (price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES ({1}, {2}, {2}, {4})".format(
    table_name, exchange_rate, buy_rate, sell_rate, date)

print x
>INSERT INTO myTable (price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES (1, 2, 2, 123)
```

Comment: I did this an it seems to be working except the date no longer has the quotes around it. is there a way to make the {4} have quotes on it only?

Comment: \'{}\' did it for me